# Displaying data that is consistent with search results on a different webpage (Typescript, html, javascript, angular2)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

**Context of problem:**

I'm making a website that is pulling search results from wikipedia and making it into an eBay project that basically allows people to bid/auction on those search results.

Screenshot of search results: [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryTlh.png)

Screenshot of the different webpage (ideally): [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xof4L.png)

I'm trying to make these variables consistent:

- item.name
- item.price
- item.quantity
- item.availability

Screenshot of error when trying to get {{item.name}} consistent: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlcovvt8x5v7cne/screenthis.png?dl=0

Code of `biddingpage.component.html` that causes error:

```
 <label for="name">Name of item: {{item.name}} </label>
        <p>
          </p>
        <label for="name">Original Price: {{item.price}} </label>
         <p>
          </p>
           <p>
          </p>
        <label for="name">Number of items in stock: {{item.quantity}} </label>
         <p>
```

Eventually I will want to attach a link and image to each item, not sure how, so it will be:

- item.image
- item.link

Link to full project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/84svnggv8xeub5m/FullProjectEbayClone.zip?dl=0

Name of code files I am changing:

- wiki.component.ts
- biddingpage.component.html
- biddingpage.component.ts

Link to plunker of full project (currently not working): http://plnkr.co/edit/1lcI4dURHwA8D9IQtqSf?p=info

Code of wiki.component.ts:

```
import { Component }        from 'angular2/core';
import { JSONP_PROVIDERS }  from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs';
import { WikipediaService } from './wikipedia.service';
import {Router, RouteParams, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'Wikithing',
  template: `
    <h1>Search and Display Page</h1>
    <p><i>Fetches after each keystroke</i></p>
    <input #term (keyup)="search(term.value)"/>
    <ul>
     <li *ngFor="#item of items | async">{{item}} <br> <p> 

     </p> Price (in USD): $ {{item.price}} <br> <p>

      </p> Availability: 24 hours <br> <p> 

      </p> Quantity currently in stock: {{quantity}}

       <br> <p> 

      </p> Image of item: <img src="http://weknowyourdreamz.com/images/apple/apple-05.jpg" alt="Apple" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
       <br> <p> 
       </p>
               <p>

            </p>
             <a [routerLink]="['BiddingPage']">Click here to bid on this item.</a>
            <p>

                </p>
        <br> <p> 
       </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers:[JSONP_PROVIDERS, WikipediaService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink],

})
export class WikiComponent {
  constructor (private wikipediaService: WikipediaService) {}
  items: Observable<string[]>;




  search (term: string) {
    this.items = this.wikipediaService.search(term);
    this.items.map((items) => items.map(() => ({
      name: items,
      prices: Math.random(),
      quantity: Math.random(),
      availability: Math.random()
    })));

    var Prices = Math.random() + Math.random();
    var quantity = Math.random();
  }

}
```

EDIT: If you have any questions but don't know the right answer please comment.

Comment: you should make a small question, not this one like 'how to do xxxxx'

Comment: @JiangYD i'm basically trying to solve this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlcovvt8x5v7cne/screenthis.png?dl=0

Comment: sorry I have no dropbox account, cannot help more

Comment: @JiangYD http://imgur.com/GtDro9o

Comment: what this code do? `this.items.map((items) => items.map(() => ({
      name: items,
      prices: Math.random(),
      quantity: Math.random(),
      availability: Math.random()
    })));`

Comment: it's supposed to set the properties of item to random numbers (except the item name which is supposed to be taken from the search results after typing in the search bar)

Comment: but `Array.map` not change the array, but create a new `Array`. your plnkr project is too big for this question, even `wiki.component.ts` not in the file list.